# Adding border to floating divs with fixed ratio

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a responsive page for my website.
Here is a mockup of what I'm making: http://dariostefanutto.com/test-work-page

The page is filled with floating divs with fixed aspect ratio. They are all based on a 4:3 ratio grid that I obtained giving a percent to the bottom padding of every div (e.g. 75% for a div with 4:3 aspect ratio).
Currently there is no space between the divs, but I want to add 1px of padding to all of them.

Now, the problem is that adding a pixel of padding changes the height of the divs, and this breaks the grid in the rows where the smaller divs are piled up vertically, because they sum up two times 2px of border (4px in total), vs the 2px of a big div.

Is there a way to add some spacing without changing the height of the divs?
Thank you!

PS: I cannot really post the code because I'm building this with Webflow.

Comment: You could use: [box-sizing: border-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Comment: "Currently there is no space between the divs, but I want to add 1px of padding to all of them." do you mean margin ?

Comment: I tried with the padding because it doesn't change the width of the divs. Otherwise the grid breaks.

Comment: do you want white gaps between the boxes or just padding in color of the box?

Comment: use the suggestion from @emmanuel ;)

Comment: @user2781994: i want gaps between the boxes.

Comment: @DarioStefanutto and are you still having any issues?

Comment: @user2781994, no that worked out thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [bootstrap framework](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

If you want responsive site, it runs with grid